# Is the verb 'stand' a state verb or an action verb?

Tags: grammar, difference

> The flowerpot **had stood** there for two years.
>
> The flowerpot **had been standing** there for two years.

Would you please tell me the differences between them? Actually I was wondering if the second sentence is correct or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "true"? We cannot know whether it is true or false.

Comment: Grammatically is it possible to say the flowerpot had been standing?

Comment: Things "stand" in the places we put them.

Comment: I know,but can we use a continues form of stand in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb 'stand' could be used in continuous form, as in:

> Multi-storey buildings are standing where houses used to be.

In this example 'stand' means: *to be situated in a particular place or position*.

from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stand)